# "Object is currently in use elsewhere", locking code is not resolving issue. C#

Tags: c#, locking, picturebox

TaW, please see my comment. My original question about multiple intermittent errors is not getting any answers and only 1 comment, perhaps it was a bit too much information for one question. So, I think it may be best to break this down into individual issues.

My primary issue is "Object is currently in use elsewhere". I've read quite a bit about this error here on stack overflow, and locking the code in question seems to be the resolution. Perhaps I'm locking it wrong, or perhaps there's some other issue, but the lock is not working for me, so I'd appreciate opinions.

My code is designed to change the color of a sample pictureBox, there are several sample pictureBoxes, the user can then decide which sample color changes to apply to their original image.

```
private object lockObject = new object();    

private void red()
{
        // declare initial variables 
        int xRed = 64;

        // Work around for "Cross-thread operation not valid" error.  This may be a VS issue, not an actual coding error. 
        if (trkColor.InvokeRequired)
            trkColor.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { xRed = trkColor.Value; }));
        else
            xRed = trkColor.Value;

        // Get bitmap from picturebox
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

        lock (lockObject)
        {

        // search through each pixel via x, y coordinates, examine and make changes. Dont let values exceed 255 or fall under 0.  
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                int myRed = c.R, myGreen = c.G, myBlue = c.B;
                myRed += xRed;
                if (myRed > 255)
                    myRed = 255;
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, myRed, myGreen, myBlue));
            }

        // assign the new bitmap to the picturebox
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bmp;
        }
}
```

Comment: TaW: I want to take a moment to thank you for going out of your way to demonstrate the lockbits code for me. The reason I didn't implement it in my project is that this is for an introductory C# class, and I need to be able to explain every line of code to my professor. I'm just not at the point where I can do that yet with lockbits.  After the class is over, and I continue working on this for my own use, I will be using the lockbits code. If you have any thoughts on this new issue, please feel free to let me know, you've always been an immense help. - Thanks

Comment: Have you tried moving the line Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;    inside the lock statement ?

Comment: Yes, just tried that, no changes, getting the same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you have this lock statement there in the first place, since only the UI thread ought to be manipulating the control anyway.

Comment: I added the lock statement because every question that I have read regarding this error on stackoverflow, and there are many, has said to add a lock statement.  I just thought I was implementing the lock incorrectly.  Thus, my original question.  However, it turns out that the lock usually doesn't work.  I think I've found what does work, I'll follow-up on that once i confirm that I'm correct.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in your application? And did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I'm not intentionally using multiple threads, but my impression is that VS can use them anyway.  Yes, I fixed it, I found the answer buried deep in the comments of the many questions here on this topic (so it's not marked as an answer).  Locking had no effect whatsoever, apparently locking doesn't lock pictureBox painting.  The answer was Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone(); at the top of the method.  The clone resolved the issue.